# Selenium Click on a ngcontent or button in python

Tags: python, selenium

This is an extract of a WebPage where I want to make a "click" on the "Nein" Button:

```
<div _ngcontent-nfa-c115="" class="col-12"><div _ngcontent-nfa-c115="" class="ets-radio-wrapper cv-radio-wrapper"><label
_ngcontent-nfa-c115="" class="ets-radio-control"><input _ngcontent-nfa-c115="" type="radio" name="vaccination-approval-checked" value="1" autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><span
_ngcontent-nfa-c115=""> Ja <br _ngcontent-nfa-c115=""><small _ngcontent-nfa-c115="">(Vermittlungscodes bereits vorhanden)</small></span></label><label _ngcontent-nfa-c115="" class="ets-radio-control"><input _ngcontent-nfa-c115="" type="radio" name="vaccination-approval-checked" value="0" autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty"><span
_ngcontent-nfa-c115="">Nein<br _ngcontent-nfa-c115=""><small _ngcontent-nfa-c115="">(Anspruch prüfen)</small></span></label></div></div>
```

The problem is that `Selenium` doesn´t find the button. Here are some examples that I tried as comments:

```
# Selenium project
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
PATH = "c:\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://lalalalal.com")
time.sleep(3)
# boton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-valid").click() -> No result
# boton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ng-valid").click() -> No result
# boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']").click() -> No result
# boton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[ng-switch-when='next']").click() -> No result
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

The problem is how to use the "find" method in order to process the click?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That radio button has a name attribute **[vaccination-approval-checked]** (see HTML) :

so try with name :

```
boton = driver.find_element_by_name("vaccination-approval-checked")
boton.click()
```